# Three.js Perspective Camera "undefined is not a function"

Tags: javascript, three.js, perspectivecamera

I have a program that used to work, but I am now getting the "undefined is not a function" error from within the three.js file.  The error is pointing to line 10466 of the uncompressed library, and this line is within the declaration of `THREE.PerspectiveCamera`.  Where is the problem?  Thanks!

```js
var assets = {};

var modelLoader = new THREE.JSONLoader(true);
modelLoader.load("assets/horse.js", onLoadedAssets);

var loading = setTimeout(function() {
    console.log("loading...");
}, 1000);

var scene, camera, renderer, controls;
var horse, box;

function init() {
    scene = new THREE.Scene();

    var w = window.innerWidth,
        h = window.innerHeight;

    camera = THREE.PerspectiveCamera(50, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);
    camera.position.y = 0;
    camera.target = new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0);

    var light1 = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xefefff, 2);
    light1.position.set(1, 1, 1).normalize();
    scene.add(light1);

    var light2 = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffefef, 2);
    light2.position.set(-1, -1, -1).normalize();
    scene.add(light2);

    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
        antialias: true
    });
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

    window.addEventListener('resize', onWindowResize, false);

    box = new Box(500, 500, 500);
    horse = new Horse();
}

function animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    render();
}


var prevTime = Date.now();

function render() {

    camera.position.x = 560 + Math.random() * 40;
    camera.position.z = 560 + Math.random() * 40;

    camera.lookAt(camera.target);

    if (horse.animation) {

        var time = Date.now();

        horse.animation.update(time - prevTime);

        prevTime = time;

    }

    renderer.render(scene, camera);

}

function onLoadedAssets(geometry) {

    clearTimeout(loading);
    console.log("loaded assets.")

    geometry.computeFaceNormals();
    geometry.computeVertexNormals();

    var material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({
        color: 0x606060,
        morphTargets: true
    });

    var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
    mesh.scale.set(1, 1, 1);

    var animation = new THREE.MorphAnimation(mesh);
    animation.play();
    animation.isPlaying = false;

    assets["horse"] = {
        mesh: mesh,
        animation: animation
    };

    init();
    animate();
}

function onWindowResize() {
    camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;

    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

    renderer.setSize(w, h);
}

function Horse() {

    var self;

    self = assets["horse"];
    scene.add(self.mesh);

    self.startMoving = function() {
        self.animation.isPlaying = true;
    };

    self.stopMoving = function() {
        self.animation.isPlaying = false;
    };

    return self;
}

function Box(xidth, yidth, zidth) {
    var self = this;

    var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(xidth, yidth, zidth);
    var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
        color: 0x666666,
        opacity: 0.4,
        transparent: true
    });
    var cube = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
    scene.add(cube);

    self.geometry = geometry;
    self.cube = cube;
}
```

Comment: Which version of the library are you linking with?

Comment: @gaitat I am linking with revision 69 of the library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your error seems to be in this line

```
camera = THREE.PerspectiveCamera(50, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);
```

Try putting a new before the THREE...

```
camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(50, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);
```